# Sum the values within the JSON Array having Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have below JSON Array and each Array Contains the Array Of Objects and Now I am want to Sum the values of the Array Objects,

Before **Downvoting**, I am asking this question to get the output considering the performance issue as I have to perform the operation on Array Of length of 1Million

Can I achieve this easily in underscore or anything other simpler way

In the Below JSON Data,

I want to get the Total Pass Count, FAIL Count and UNEXECUTED Count and Total Count

**OutPut Expecting**

Project ID : 12151
Pass Count : 7
Fail Count : 3
UNEXECUTED Count : 9
totalExecutions : 19

Project ID : 12152
Pass Count : 8
Fail Count : 10
UNEXECUTED Count : 2
totalExecutions : 20

```
[
  {
    "projectId": 12151,
    "PASS": 7,
    "FAIL": 3,
    "UNEXECUTED": 9,
    "TOTAL": 19
  },
  {
    "projectId": 12152,
    "PASS": 8,
    "FAIL": 10,
    "UNEXECUTED": 2,
    "TOTAL": 20
  }
]
```

INPUT JSON

```
[
  {
    "4106": {
      "totalExecutions": 11,
      "projectId": 12151,
      "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
          {
            "count": 3,
            "statusName": "UNEXECUTED"
          },
          {
            "count": 5,
            "statusName": "PASS"
          },
          {
            "count": 3,
            "statusName": "FAIL"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "4107": {
      "totalExecutions": 8,
      "projectId": 12151,
      "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
          {
            "count": 6,
            "statusName": "UNEXECUTED"
          },
          {
            "count": 2,
            "statusName": "PASS"
          },
          {
            "count": 0,
            "statusName": "FAIL"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "recordsCount": 2
  },
  {
    "4047": {
      "totalExecutions": 9,
      "projectId": 12152,
      "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
          {
            "count": 0,
            "statusName": "UNEXECUTED"
          },
          {
            "count": 3,
            "statusName": "PASS"
          },
          {
            "count": 6,
            "statusName": "FAIL"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "4048": {
      "totalExecutions": 6,
      "projectId": 12152,
      "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
          {
            "count": 2,
            "statusName": "UNEXECUTED"
          },
          {
            "count": 2,
            "statusName": "PASS"
          },
          {
            "count": 2,
            "statusName": "FAIL"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "4049": {
      "totalExecutions": 5,
      "projectId": 12152,
      "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
          {
            "count": 0,
            "statusName": "UNEXECUTED"
          },
          {
            "count": 3,
            "statusName": "PASS"
          },
          {
            "count": 2,
            "statusName": "FAIL"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "recordsCount": 3
  }
]
```

Below is my approach to find the value, let me know how to make it optmized or even faster

```
function findtheTotal() {
    return getTheLiveDayUpdates().then(function (items) {
        var TotalCount = 0;
        angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
            angular.forEach(item, function (eachValue) {
                TotalCount = TotalCount + eachValue.totalExecutions;
               console.log("Total", TotalCount);
            }); 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because [It appears no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). After you write some code you should then [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: No, I pretty much aware of the logic which I can do by using `angular.forEach`, But wanted to know easiest and better performance oriented, I don't need the code at least any suggestions should be helpful for me

Comment: But you neglected to include it or give any indication as to what the benchmark(s) were running your `forEach` over a sample data set. Again, it *looks* as if you did not attempt to answer your own problem. We can't guess as to what you did try if you do not include it in your question.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the logic, let me know your suggestions on that, Thanks!!

Comment: 1. That does not match the response you are trying to build. 2. Where is the bench marking that you did to indicate that the approach is slow?

Comment: Yes That is why I am asking the suggestions!! I am noob in handling very large data I need your suggestions not the code

Comment: Again, how can you know your code is non performant if you have not even attempted to write the complete code yet? Write the *working* code first, see if it works, then see if it is performant. If it is not performant then come back and update your question with the **complete working code** (ie. the loops) and what your benchmark results are (ie. how long does it take to load XXX data).